# Resolving Artifacts from bintray via gradle (non jcenter)

Tags: android, maven, gradle, aar, bintray

I've deployed artifact to bintray as it whitten in documentation (using their plugin). All looks fine. It is opened in browder, structure looks fine: https://dl.bintray.com/flymob/maven/

Now I want to use it via gradle in Android Studio before publishing to jcenter(). I've read their documentation https://bintray.com/docs/usermanual/formats/formats_mavenrepositories.html#_working_with_gradle

I've tried:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://dl.bintray.com/flymob/maven"
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
compile 'flymob-sdk-sample:FlyMobSdk:1.3.0'
```

or

```
compile 'flymob-sdk-sample:FlyMobSdk:1.3.0@aar'
```

I'm getting error:
Failed to resolve: flymob-sdk-sample:FlyMobSdk:1.3.0

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

you added `"https://dl.bintray.com/flymob/maven"` inside the `buildscript` section. Those are the repos used by the buildscript (a.k.a. gradle script) only. Those are the repos where the system will find the plugins from `apply plugin`

to fix it is easy. Just move it to the `repositories` on the "root" of the script. Something like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // repos for the build script
        jcenter()
        ... etc
    }

    dependencies {
        // dependencies from the plugins from the build script
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        ... etc
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'
apply plugin: ... etc

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/flymob/maven" } <<<<< HERE 
}

dependencies {
    compile ... etc
```